# build failed error in android when I replace low quality png image with HD png image

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to android. I am getting this strange error that I was using a low quality png image as background for startup screen but Now I got HD Image of the same and replaced that low quality image with HD image. But I am getting this strange build error.

```
Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Mubashir.gul\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Mubashir.gul\AndroidStudioProjects\Highrise\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\logo.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Mubashir.gul\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
```

Even if I dont use that image in any of the activities and I just place that image into my project folder like drawable it results in the above error.

Comment: instead of using HD image.. try to another use image.. and please check if  it ll be raised again same ?

Comment: It works fine but if I use low quality image it becomes blur

Comment: then use 9 patch image it ll be solve your image blur problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the latest version of the `build tools`. you will get it from sdk manager. Give it a try and let me know the progress.
You are facing similar problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821614/android-studio-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexception).

If you are using images for setting background image in activity then it is recommended that image should be from `drawable` folder. `Mipmap` is used only for Icons. So try using it from drawables than `mipmap`. 
 I hope it helps.