# Unable to set layout background from drawable

Tags: android

I'm unable to set my MainActivity background from a drawable image:

```
android:background="@drawable/loli"
```

`loli` is my drawable name. Actually nothing special, just the usual to get a simple background. When I use it my xml, I'm getting this error while running:

```
Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/firas/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/firas/AndroidStudioProjects/NeverLost/app/src/main/res/drawable/back.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/firas/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when gradle fails to process resources. In your case it may have happened to be an invalid image file in the drawable folder.

Please check both ways

**1> check your extension & convert them .png into .jpeg**

**2> if that useless then delete from drawable**

Please visit [Android Studio Error: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821614/android-studio-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexception) or this link for more help [Android Studio crash (aapt.exe returns 42) when I put PNG file in drawable folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023830/android-studio-crash-aapt-exe-returns-42-when-i-put-png-file-in-drawable-folde)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning/rebuilding your project.

Build > Clean Project or Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: I did it over and over and itdidn't work Iwant to know if the resolution of drawable or its size has any effect .

Comment: Are you sure that this drawable file exists:
/NeverLost/app/src/main/res/drawable/back.png

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your answers
the links you provide me were very useful (first one).
actually the problem was not changing the image extension .
because I was saving .jpeg extensions as .png from google image 
I think it's much suitable to keep the default extension .
At least that worked for me